# "failed to fetch error" when running "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade"

Tags: apt, package-management

I see this error and these warnings when running apt commands:

Results of `sudo apt update` :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'packages.microsoft.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Results of `sudo apt upgrade` :

```
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.18-1~20.04
  Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.18-1~20.04 [1,270 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libpython2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.18-1~20.04 [335 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mutter-common all 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 [12.8 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gir1.2-mutter-6 amd64 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 [110 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libmutter-6-0 amd64 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 [1,168 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mutter amd64 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2 [128 kB]
Fetched 3,515 kB in 39s (89.8 kB/s)                                            
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.18-1~20.04_amd64.deb  Undetermined Error [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Results of `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8` :

```
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 172.978/212.903/252.643/30.728 ms
```

Comment: It looks like it could be a simple network connectivity error. Please perform a simple ping check with `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8` to check what kind of bandwidth you're getting. It should be less than 100 ms.

Comment: `4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms`  ---
`rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 172.978/212.903/252.643/30.728 ms`